# Emacs org-babel with ob-julia.el does not work anymore with Julia V1.0

Tags: emacs, julia, org-babel

I am using [ob-julia.el](https://github.com/gjkerns/ob-julia/blob/master/ob-julia-doc.org) to create my Julia notebooks under Emacs. However with the new Julia **v1.0** release it does not work anymore.

For instance a basic org-mode document like this one:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC julia :exports both :session mySession
1+2
#+END_SRC
```

returns now an empty `#+RESULT`

If I look at **mySession** buffer I see this error message

```
julia> ERROR: UndefVarError: writecsv not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the Emacs package [ob-julia.el](https://github.com/gjkerns/ob-julia) has not been upgraded to support the lastest v1.0 Julia release.

In this v1.0 version, the `readcsv` and `writecsv` functions do not exist anymore. They have been remplaced by the [DelimitedFiles.readdlm](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/DelimitedFiles/index.html#DelimitedFiles.readdlm-Tuple%7BAny,AbstractChar,Type,AbstractChar%7D) and [DelimitedFiles.writedlm](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/DelimitedFiles/index.html#DelimitedFiles.writedlm) functions.

However [ob-julia.el](https://github.com/gjkerns/ob-julia/blob/master/ob-julia.el) still uses them:

```
(defvar org-babel-julia-write-object-command "writecsv(\"%s\",%s)")
```

and

```
 (format "%s = readcsv(\"%s\")" name file)
    (format "%s = readcsv(\"%s\")"
        name file))))
```

I have submitted an [ob-julia.el issue](https://github.com/gjkerns/ob-julia/issues/13). However there is a possible quick and dirty fix if you want to still use `ob-julia.el` right now. Simply add these lines in your `~/.julia/config/startup.jl` file:

```
import DelimitedFiles

function writecsv(filename::AbstractString,ans)
    DelimitedFiles.writedlm(filename,ans,',')
end

function readcsv(filename::AbstractString)
    DelimitedFiles.readdlm(filename,',')
end
```

This will redefine the `readcsv` and `writecsv` functions and make ob-julia.el work again.

With this fix, I get now:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC julia
1+2
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 3

#+BEGIN_SRC julia :session mySession
1+2
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 3
```

as expected.

Comment: This breaks building several Julia packages for me. As a workaround-workaround, I moved it to `~/.julia/config/startup-babel.jl`.

Then I customized `Ess Julia`'s `Inferior Julia Args` variable to

`-e include("$(ENV["HOME"])/.julia/config/startup-babel.jl") -i`

Comment: @BillBurdick Thanks for this valuable feedback. If you want to add an answer I will upvote. There is a discussion here [julia.discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/straw-poll-for-emacs-org-mode-workflow/10369/22. The problem is that ob-julia is not maintained anymore. A solution is to use [ob-ipython](https://github.com/gregsexton/ob-ipython) (with Julia kernel) however this is not a lightweight solution as the pure elisp ob-julia solution.

Comment: added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This breaks building several Julia packages for me. As a workaround-workaround, I moved Picaud's code to `~/.julia/config/startup-babel.jl`.

UPDATE:

That customization no longer seems to work. This one works for me. Do M-x customize-apropos and search for julia. Find `Org Babel Julia Command` and set it to (you may want your own path to Julia in there, of course):

```
julia -e 'include("$(ENV["HOME"])/.julia/config/startup-babel.jl")' -i
```

OLD CUSTOMIZATION THAT NO LONGER WORKS FOR ME:

Then I customized `Ess Julia`'s `Inferior Julia Args` variable to

```
-e include("$(ENV["HOME"])/.julia/config/startup-babel.jl") -i
```

Comment: What variable is that exactly? And what should the exact syntax be? I'm just a child.

Comment: It seems like some things have changed. I updated the workaround above.